# Где найти build.gradle в android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Наверное глупый вопрос, но я так и не смог найти этот файл. Подскажите пожалуйста где его можно найти, многие новички не понимают банальных вещей.
Ну а вообще, я ищу его из-за того, что появилась ошибка

```
Error:(4, 23) java: package org.apache.http does not exist
```

Google подсказал, что нужно добавить в build.gradle следующую строку.

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Есть какие нибудь мысли, правильно ли я понял и то ли решение нашел?

Comment: так вы build.gradle ищите или либу не можете подключить?
Попробуйте это ссылку http://stackoverflow.com/q/31433687/5634351

Answer (score 2):

В разделе "Project" выбираешь тип показа Android, там открываешь раздел "Gradle Script" и там будет 2 файла buld.gradle, тебе нужен файл buld.gradle(Module:app), вот и искомый файл. При работе с файлами gradle аккуратней т.к если что-нибудь не так, то твой проект просто не соберётся.

Answer (score 2):

Тип отображения 'Android', вкладка 'Gradle Scripts'.

[image: файл]

Comment: У меня нет такого раздела. Как его установить то?

Comment: @АльбертУшаков Он должен быть как колонка в левой части,  шириной с четверть экрана. Возможно он просто скрыт. На левой стороне студии есть узкая вертикальная панель( как на скриншотее) и там нажмите на "1: Project"

Answer (score 1):

Найти можно в папке с проектом и без AndroidStudio,   а в AS можно в боковой вкладке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]